# Checking whether the user input is a str in Python

Tags: python

I checked various questions on Stack Overflow but one thing every logic lacks. Let me demonstrate using Python:

```
while True:
    user_input = raw_input()
    if type(user_input) == str:
        print 'ERROR'
    else:
        print 'BINGO'
```

Also, we cannot use input() in place of raw_input() as it gives the error:Traceback (most recent call last):

```
File ".\test.py", line 3, in <module>
    user_input = int(input())
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'asdf' is not defined
```

The problem here is that raw_input converts the user input into string so it always prints 'ERROR' and if I change the second line to

```
user_input = int(raw_input)
```

then, it gives an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\test.py", line 3, in <module>
    user_input = int(raw_input())
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'asdf'
```

I tried this with try and except but it shall work fine to check integer but not a string.

Comment: Hmmm, how exactly do you want `raw_input` to *know* that the next keystrokes by the user will be an integer?  Conversely, how do you expect the `int` function to cast `"asdf"` into an integer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You got it all backwards - `raw_input` **does not** "convert the user input into string" - the user input was a string to begin with! It's `input` that converts it to other things.

If you want to use `raw_input`, you can assume you'll get a string and you need to convert it to int yourself. As you have seen, this fails if the string does not represent an integer, but you can easily catch that error:

```
while True:
    user_input = raw_input()
    try:
        user_input_as_integer = int(user_input)
        print 'BINGO'
    except ValueError:
        print 'ERROR'
```

Comment: You got one write out of two. Go through this https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#raw_input

Comment: OK, so it says that `raw_input` converts the input into a string - but that conversion is not in the way implied from your question. When the user enters the input `10`, for example, `raw_input` does not convert it from the int `10` to the string `'10'` - it was never an int in the first place. What the documentation means is that `raw_input` converts the input from a byte array or a buffer or something like that to a Python string object.

Answer (score -1):

```
# first store the value to a variable
user_input = raw_input('>')
try:
    if int(user_input):
        print "User entered %d is integer" % int(user_input)
except ValueError: 
    # check whether the user entered string or not
    print "User entered %s is a string" % user_input
```

The `raw_input` always stores string whether you enter an integer.